# Starting an iPhone app in camera mode shows just a blank screen

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I'm creating an app for the iPhone which is supposed to start in camera mode (with a custom layout on top but that comes later). I've already created a version of this app where I press a button, that allows me to either choose a photo from the iPhone album or take a new photo.

Trying to use the same code in a different fails.

Originally I had a function 'takePicture' which I used to start the camera

```
- (void)takePicture
{   
    isInCaptureMode = YES;

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    imagePicker.mediaTypes =
    [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

    imagePicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;

    // set delegate
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];

    // Place image picker on the screen
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

    [imagePicker release];
}
```

So I thought to myself "I can probably create a single view app, throw this code into the view controller's viewDidLoad function and use that as a starting point". But alas, I've been stuck there. When I do that the application starts and (if the device has a camera) the screen goes blackish blank, if the device does not have a camera (iPad or the simulator) the app crashes.

I originally created the app using Xcode 3 but have now migrated over to 4.2 the original app runs fine in 4.2 though (after I did a little bit of tweaking)

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Just found out what was wrong... I need to call my code in 'viewDidAppear' instead of 'viewDidLoad'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, like I said in the comment. As soon as I called the code from 'viewDidAppear' instead of 'viewDidLoad' it finally ran...

Answer (score 1):

can you try the following code to see what happen?

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
} else {
  //you can get picture from Library is there is no camera 
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}

picker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

[picker release];
```

Comment: I had planned to implement this once I'd got the camera up and running. I did try creating a test project where I was going to try your code. There I noticed the 'viewDidAppear' method. So have some points!